# What test should I use to classify this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Classify 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ x^2+\cos^n x}{n^2}$$
as absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent.

I am not sure whether I should use integral test or comparison test.

Do you know what's the best test to classify this series?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

$$\left | \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ x^2+\cos^n x}{n^2}\right |  \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x^2+\cos^n{x}|}{n^2} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ x^2+1}{n^2} = (x^2+1) \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Therefore the sum is absolutely convergent for any finite value of $x$ by the comparison test.  Thanks to @N.S. and @vadim123 for correcting and clarifying the reasoning here.

Comment: I misread, my bad.

Comment: how did you did pie^2/6?

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$  This is a well-known sum.

Comment: oh i see. for this kind of series, is it best to use comparison test?

Comment: @Risa: yes, that's correct.

Comment: @N.S.: have you seen the edited answer?

Comment: @vadim123: OK, thanks, I see.

Comment: @RonGordon Now it is fine, excepting that the absolute value should be inside the sum ;) You can also prove that the series is positive, but this is much simpler. :)

Comment: how do you get sum of [(x^2)+1]/n^2?

Comment: @Risa: Note that $|\cos^n{x}| \le 1$

Comment: is because cos x is 1?